# How to add data to user node in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm implementing an app which uses Firebase for authentication and that works fine. What I want to do now is to add some more data in the "users" node in the real time database. Because of that I changed the database roles and now they look like this.

```
`{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}`
```

Right now I have some code that works for saving the data in the "users" JSON node and this is that code:

```
 ` mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {


                    DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                    dbRef.child("users").child(task.getResult().getUser().getUid()).push().setValue"jovan").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Log.i("info", "createUserInDatabase:success");
                            } else {
                                Log.i("info", "createUserInDatabase:failure");
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    Log.i("Info", "" + task.getResult().getUser().getUid());
                    Log.i("info", "createUserWithEmail:success");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registered and logged in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Log.i("info", "createUserWithEmail:failure");
                }
            }
        });`
```

As I said this code works but when I took a look in the Firebase I found out that my data need to be more structured and easy to read.

[image]

Here is a link of what I want to do, the content is on the second answer. [Stack Overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39076988/add-extra-user-information-with-firebase).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of pushing, create the user child in users node with the uid of that user. Then set user details to that node.

```
bRef.child("users").child(uid).setValueAsync(otherUserData)
// otherUserData is a map or an object containing other user data
```

Your data structure will look like this.

users

--> -L3NpAd......

----> name: "jovan"

----> age: 20