# How to add JSON object with specific Key name in Firebase Database Android

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a application which works on `Firebase Database`.After successfull Login of a user created in Firebase using `Firebase Auth` user is saving some data in Firebase.The requirement is I need to add the data `POST` by that user with some key to identify data.

```
[
{
    "key":"Satyam",
    "value":"some data"
},
{
    "key":"Akash",
    "value":"some data"
},
{
    "key":"Yash",
    "value":"some data"
}
]
```

Suppose user Satyam has login using credentials of `Firebase Auth`,so data POST by Satyam need to be added in database where key is Satyam. How to achieve this ?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39076988/add-extra-user-information-with-firebase

Comment: @Satyam: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is. Can you update your question to show what you've already tried?

Comment: I have used `FirebaseAuth` for creating account of  user.Suppose a user Log in with credentials and adding some data to database. I should be able to understand that data is added by that specific user.I am thinking of identifier as a `Key` in JSON return by Firebase database when data is returned.