# Firebase add authenticated users to database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I made a swift ios app where the user can create a profile and log into it via firebase. 
But i made it with Authentication,not with Database.

(Im very beginner in Firebase and in Swift too.)

Is there any way to import the data from Users to a Database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing prebuilt for that. Most developers add the users to their database from within their client app when the sign-up (or sign-in) completes.

Also see:

- [How do I link each user to their data in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30910704/how-do-i-link-each-user-to-their-data-in-firebase)
- [Adding new data to firebase users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46657445/adding-new-data-to-firebase-users)
- [Add extra User Information with firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39076988/add-extra-user-information-with-firebase)