# Add extra fields with Firebase User Management

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Authentication in my Angular (v 8) project. Everything is working fine with Email Address and Password.

Now, as per the requirement, I also want to store First Name, Last Name, Gender, User Type, Occupation, Hobby fields along with Email and Password. From some links like [Add extra User Information with firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39076988/add-extra-user-information-with-firebase), it looks like I need to use Firebase Database.

Is there any other way to store those fields without the Database? If No, then which database is good for me (Realtime or Cloud Filestore)? I just want User Management in my project.

Comment: FYI: asking for product recommendation is off topic for Stack Overflow.  But if you have data you want to store per user, you should probably find some database to do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other way to store those fields without the Database?

No, you can't.

> Which database is good for me (Realtime or Cloud Filestore)? I just want User Management in my project.

As the information you're going to store has a "simple" structure, your choice will hardly depend on what kind of search are you going to do. I would suggest going for firestore because of the query and indexing capabilities. Also security with firestore uses IAM and the rules are not in cascade (more information about that in here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore) which provide a lot more options.

Comment: @jeetenparmar While this answer is good, it may or may not be correct based on how you use your database as Firestore and the Real Time Data Base have different pricing structures. For example. if you are frequently reading a tiny amount of data for each user, the RTDB is probably better as it charges only for bandwidth and storage, not operations performed. Whereas Firestore Charges primarily on operations performed in your database (read, write, delete) so if you are doing frequent reads, Firestore will cost more.