# I want the details taken from Authentication method Convert to real time database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I made a register app in Android studio. For that I used firebase
authentication method.
When registering, the user has to enter his name, phone number, password and email.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9DFO.jpg)

In authentication only the email is saved.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQCAf.jpg)

If I can change this data to real time database I can save all the details. How to do it? I want a way to convert the details taken from this Authentication to a real time database. thank you.

Comment: I recommend searching for similar questions before posting your own: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-authentication%5D%5Bandroid%5D+save+user+to+database For example this question has some solid answers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39076988/209103

Answer (score 0):

you can retrieve data from auth using

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null) {
    // Name, email address, and profile photo Url
    String name = user.getDisplayName();
    String email = user.getEmail();
    Uri photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl();
   }
```

here's the [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start#access_user_information) for complete details about what you can get from auth user and later you can save it in your db.

you user must have signed in using signin [methods](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start#sign_in_existing_users).

Answer (score 0):

**Adding to @Haider Saleem answer:**

You can also save all the values to Firebase Firestore (*use the Firebase's Firestore instead of realtime database for better performance and lower cost*). You would need the user's UID which you can get by:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String uid = user.getUid();
```

Then you can create a document in Firestore with the user's UID as follows:

```
 FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    db.collection(//collection Name)
            .document(uid)
            .set(//the object - HashMap or custom object))
```

And get the data like:

```
 FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
 FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    db.collection(//collection name)
            .document(user.getUid())
            .get()
```

**I suggest you to read the following:**

1. [Add Data to cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data)
2. [Cloud Firestore Data Model](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model)
3. [Get Data with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)