# Firebase registered with email and pass - how add additional details to the users

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I know this has been discussed plenty of times, unfortunately I am a noob and didn`t find the answers useful enough.
Basically, my app registers the users to Firebase using the email and pass registration method. I also need another 2 fields for the users, name and lastname. I understand these have to be saved in
the Realtime Database.
This is my code:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.UserProfileChangeRequest;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText editTextEmail;
    EditText editTextPassword;
    EditText editTextRePassword;
    EditText editTextName;
    EditText editTextLastName;
    Button buttonSignup;
    TextView textViewSignin;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //initializing firebase auth object
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        //if getCurrentUser does not returns null
        if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
            //that means user is already logged in
            //so close this activity
            finish();

            //and open profile activity
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class));
        }

        //initializing views
        editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        editTextRePassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextRePassword);
        editTextName = (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        editTextLastName = (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.editTextLastName);
        textViewSignin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSignin);

        buttonSignup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSignup);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        //attaching listener to button
        buttonSignup.setOnClickListener(this);
        textViewSignin.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    private boolean isValidEmail(String email){
        boolean isValidEmail = false;

        String regExpn = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";

        CharSequence inputStr = email;

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regExpn, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
        if (email.matches(regExpn))
        {
            isValidEmail = true;
        }
        return isValidEmail;
    }


    private void registerUser(){

        //getting email and password from edit texts
        String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String password  = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
        String repass = editTextRePassword.getText().toString().trim();
        String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
        String lastname = editTextLastName.getText().toString().trim();


        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter the password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() ;
            return;
        }


        else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(repass)){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please repeat the password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        else if (!password.equals(repass)) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"You must input the same password as in the previous field",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        else if(!isValidEmail(email.toString().trim()))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please use a valid email address",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;

        }

        else if (password.length()<6) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Your password must be at least 6 characters long",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(name)){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter your name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() ;
            return;
        }

        else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(lastname)){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please input your last name",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }


        progressDialog.setMessage("Registering, please wait...");
        progressDialog.show();

        //creating a new user
        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        //checking if success
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                            
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class));
                        }else{
                            //display some message here
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Registration Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if(view == buttonSignup){
            registerUser();
        }

        if(view == textViewSignin){
            //open login activity when user taps on the already registered textview
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
        }

    }

}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: Basically, I`m missing the part of the code that creates the records in the Firebase Database. My code only allow registration of users and login

Comment: What do you mean by "missing the part of the code that creates the records"?

Comment: Well, it translate as " I don`t know what to do in order to add the name of the user ( registered with email and pass) in the Firebase Realtime Database.

Answer (score 1):

See this Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39077132/7160752

You would have to create a `users` child in your database that contains all the extra user information. The way I do this is after a user successfully signs up, you can store their info under `users/:userId`

```
@Override
  public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < AuthResult > task){
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
      // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
      Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success");

      User user = new User(name, email, phoneNumber);
      FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser()).setValue(user);

      updateUI(user);
    } else {
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: How would the updateUI method should look like? Thanks

Comment: In your case, it would simple be starting a new activity